# Trying to write a python app that reads phone numbers from a file

Tags: python-2.7

I am quite new to Python. At the moment I am trying to write a script that can read a `.txt` file that contains a bunch of data, and pull out phone numbers that are in the format of `(xxx)xxx-xxxx`.

Here is my current attempt, but its not working at all and I am lost:

```
#import argv
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt_file = open(filename)
indata = txt_file.read()

#confirm to the user what file is being open
print "Opening %r" % filename

#create a loop to read through the file
for line, in line enumerate(indata):
    if line == "(" + \w\w\w\ + ")" + \w\w\w "-" + \w\w\w
    print line

txt_file.close()
```

Can anyone provide me with a suggestion on how to make this work?

Comment: Could you please post what your txt file looks like. like first 3 lines is fine...

Comment: and add error msg or your explanation what is not working..

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

```
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1] #Grabs first argument

#confirm to the user what file is being open
print "Opening %r" % filename

with open(filename,'rb') as txt_file: #Opens the file
    for line in txt_file:  #Reads the file line by line.
        if ####    #checks for ...
```

Sys.argv is a list, so the first argument passed is sys.argv[1]. You don't need script because you don't use it. Don't use read() because that stores the entire file as a list and all you need to do is check each line. Use with for good measures when you're opening/writing/closing files. with closes the file as you exit the block.

I'll need to see what your text file looks like to finish.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions thus far. That is a far better approach.

Comment: I would also suggest looking into module regex (regular expressions - pattern recognition). import re